# similar function to php's str_replace in python?

Tags: python

is there a similar function in python that takes search(array) and replace(array) as a parameter? Then takes a value from each array and uses them to do search and replace on subject(string).

I know I can achieve this using for loops, but just looking more elegant way.

Comment: See previous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175540/iterative-find-replace-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-python/1175554#1175554

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the answer is no.

I would specify your search/replace strings in a list, and the iterate over it:

```
edits = [(search0, replace0), (search1, replace1), (search2, replace2)] # etc.
for search, replace in edits:
    s = s.replace(search, replace)
```

Even if python did have a `str_replace`-style function, I think I would still separate out my search/replace strings as a list, so really this is only taking one extra line of code.

Finally, this is a programming language after all.  If it doesn't supply the function you want, you can always define it yourself.

Comment: yes, you are rigth. but builtin functions tend to be more efficient.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that edit #2 might replace something inserted by the edits before it, which I would expect to be absolutely to avoid.

Comment: @kaizer.se: Yes, this is true. I don't know PHP but http://nz.php.net/str_replace says: "If search  or replace  are arrays, their elements are processed first to last." Only replacing non-overlapping search strings would be a difficult problem, I think.

Comment: @Ainab: Sure, but remember what they say about premature optimization. I expect this simple code to be _fast enough_ for most situations.  If you've profiled it and you need more speed, you could ask another question: "How can I speed this up?"

Answer (score 2):

Heh - you could use the one-liner below whose elegance is second only to its convenience :-P

(Acts like PHP when search is longer than replace, too, if I read that correctly in the PHP docs.):

**** Edit: This new version works for all sized substrings to replace. ****

```
>>> subject = "Coming up with these convoluted things can be very addictive."
>>> search = ['Coming', 'with', 'things', 'addictive.', ' up', ' these', 'convoluted ', ' very']
>>> replace = ['Making', 'Python', 'one-liners', 'fun!']
>>> reduce(lambda s, p: s.replace(p[0],p[1]),[subject]+zip(search, replace+['']*(len(search)-len(replace))))
'Making Python one-liners can be fun!'
```

Comment: Neat. Itertools can continue sequences better: `def cont(seq, elem=None): return itertools.chain(seq, itertools.repeat(elem))`; now use `cont(replace, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Do it with regexps:

```
import re

def replace_from_list(replacements, str):
    def escape_string_to_regex(str):
        return re.sub(r"([\\.^$*+?{}[\]|\(\)])", r"\\\1", str)

    def get_replacement(match):
        return replacements[match.group(0)]

    replacements = dict(replacements)
    replace_from = [escape_string_to_regex(r) for r in replacements.keys()]
    regex = "|".join(["(%s)" % r for r in replace_from])
    repl = re.compile(regex)

    return repl.sub(get_replacement, str)

# Simple replacement:
assert replace_from_list([("in1", "out1")], "in1") == "out1"

# Replacements are never themselves replaced, even if later search strings match
# earlier destination strings:
assert replace_from_list([("1", "2"), ("2", "3")], "123") == "233"

# These are plain strings, not regexps:
assert replace_from_list([("...", "out")], "abc ...") == "abc out"
```

Using regexps for this makes the searching fast.  This won't iteratively replace replacements with further replacements, which is *usually* what's wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Made a tiny recursive function for this

```
def str_replace(sbjct, srch, rplc):
    if len(sbjct) == 0:
        return ''

    if len(srch) == 1:
        return sbjct.replace(srch[0], rplc[0])

    lst = sbjct.split(srch[0])
    reslst = []
    for s in lst:
        reslst.append(str_replace(s, srch[1:], rplc[1:]))
    return rplc[0].join(reslst);
```