# replace empty string(s) in tuple

Tags: python

Is there an easy way (hopefully a one liner) to replace '' with something like '-'?
Many thanks.

```
tup = (1,2,'ABC','','','','text')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175540/iterative-find-replace-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: I hope you are aware that tuples are immutable. You can do it, but that will create a new tuple (so references might break).

Comment: Why do people specifically want one-liners?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about the following?

```
 tuple('-' if x == '' else x for x in tup)
```

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) comments, [tuples are immutable](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/tuples.html), so the best you can do is to return a new one.

Comment: As a very minor point, I'd probably reverse it and write it as `tuple(x if x != '' else '-' for x in tup)`, since the usual, expected case is non-empty.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Or more succinctly: `tuple(x if x else '-' for x in tup)`

Comment: @Adeel: That won't work if OP wants to preserve other values interpreted as false, such as `False`, `0`, `[]`, etc.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield:  You are absolutely correct.  Despite the example provided by the OP, I erroneously assumed that the tuple is homogeneous.