# When creating a namedtuple, how do I substitute a value?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, namedtuple

I'm pulling data from the **NHTSA API**, using a JSON format. I'm then creating a named tuple from this data and a few other sources and using this as a record to insert into a **MySQL** database.

The **NHTSA API** uses `''` to designate a null value which is not an accepted value in for this particular column in database. The column only allows a `float` datatype.

When creating my named tuple, is there a way to substitute `None` if a specific value is returned? I.e. if API call returns `''`, use `None` instead?

**Error returned is**

> Failed inserting object into MySQL table Error while executing statement: Data truncated for column 'weight' at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, hence you need to create a new tuple

Here's an **example**:

```py
old = (1,2,'ABC','','','','text')

new = tuple(None if x == '' else x for x in old)
```

**Output**:
Now `new` contains:

```py
(1, 2, 'ABC', None, None, None, 'text')
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200154/replace-empty-strings-in-tuple) thread for more information

Answer (score 0):

To replace one specific field value in `namedtuple` / `NamedTuple` in an easier way you can use `_replace()` method.

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x,y')
p = Point(x=11, y=22)
p = p._replace(x=33)
print(p)
```

It will print:

```
Point(x=33, y=22)
```

`_replace()` substitutes a field specified with keyword argument with its value, and returns a new `namedtuple` with that value and the rest of values copied from an old `namedtuple`.